# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer autorotation under Size classes

Tags: ios, calayer, ios-autolayout, size-classes, autorotate

I am manually creating an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer (a type of CALayer) once an AVCaptureSession starts running and adding it to UIView as follows:

```
 func captureSessionStartedRunning(session:AVCaptureSession?) {
    if let captureSession = session {
        if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.init(session: captureSession) {
            previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        }
    }
}
```

I am not experienced with Autorotation with Size Classes, so can somebody tell me what is the easiest way to deal with autorotation here?

Answer (score 2):

Override:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubViews()
    previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

Whenever your views layout changes it will update the size of the layer to be the size of the view.

You may also want to change the `.videoGravity` of the previewLayer to `.aspectFill`